# using redis session provider for asp.net I can find the hash and field but not the values.

Tags: asp.net, redis

After i installed it it works just fine. However when I look at the data In the Redis database I see that a hash with the correct fields has been created but the fields don't have any values that I can see in them. i tried HGETALL {hashkey} and HGET {hashkey} {fieldname}, It returns the field names, but no values appear. what am I missing?

Comment: Can you connect with redis-cli and run MONITOR? With that command, you will see everything that Redis receives. That may give you some information about what's actually happening.

Comment: thanks, seems to be using bytes and not a regular string to store the data. i wish there was a way to change this, however the it is not an open source library. I still don't understand why i cant get the bytes when doing HGET KEY FIELD. OMG, it's even worse, it's a mix of bytes and xml.

Comment: See my explanation, also, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

that's my library you're referring to I believe. Let me explain the xml, it's a good horror story. Originally, we used ServiceStack's json serializer classes, which did not have the ability to serialize `DataTable`s. Then, in our production site which we inherited from a previous team, there were several `Session` keys that stored `DataTable`s, and we did not know where they were or that they even existed.

So when we rolled out RedisSessionProvider to the site, there were quite a few unexepcted crashes and I ended up adding a lot of the logging delegates that finally allowed us to see the object types we were serrializing.

There's a post from mythz, the creator of ServiceStack, somewhere that says something like `DataTable` were not really meant to be serialized to JSON to begin with because they do some very wacky things with namespaces and circular references that made it difficult to express in JSON. At the end of the day, they decided not to provide that functionality at all, and even worse, the exception message that occurred did not mention this limitation explicitly enough to tell from the logs.

Finally tracked it down, and needed to fix it quickly, and assumed that it was an edge case that was rare so I just used the basic .NET xml serializer which does work with `DataTable`s as a quick fix. The bytes at the front are not bytes, but rather an identifier string for the type of object being stored in the redis hash key (because JSON is typeless). You'll find similar type hints for all the keys, and you have control to override it from the library ([RedisJSONSerializer.cs](https://github.com/welegan/RedisSessionProvider/blob/master/RedisSessionProvider/Serialization/RedisJSONSerializer.cs) look for `typeInfoPattern` and override it)

---

TL:DR; It's not a great idea to store `DataTable`s in `Session`, but it's something we should be able to support more easily now that we use JSON.NET as the serialization library anyways. So I'll try to patch that up when I get a chance, it should slim down the space `DataTable`s take up in your Redis hash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact yours is not the library that i was writing a bout (your is open source, this one is not.) how ever i did also give your a try. the way I see type declared in json most often is by adding a property $type. this is what Json.net does and i think it works well, it is still valid json and that is important to me. i was not storing datatables in session. but the implementation im still using uses xml for everything.

Comment: Huh, given the symptoms you were describing I was so sure it was my library. Oh well. Thanks for the `$type` hint, I may end up relying on JSON.NET to remember type instead, would de-bloat my code a little.

Comment: Not that i'm doing you a favor (other way around) but if you do that i will switch to your library. my main pain points with the current one are:closed source,no choice of serializer,xml, no choice of redis client and no control over what happens on deserialize failure. stack exchange. redis has been giving me trouble(different discussion) and i had more luck with csRedis.

Comment: De-coupling redis client is a good idea, I'll give it some thought. No guarantees though. As for the other features, those already exist in my library but requires some coding on your part. The documentation on the github page points out all of the logging delegates, and the link in my answer is an example of a serializer that plugs in to my RedisSessionProvider, and you can set the default one.